# In rails 7, How to store in users table (colonne country) full country name with gem 'select_country'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 7, with Devise, gem wicked and select_country installed.
in my view, views/after_register/step2.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: wizard_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :location, placeholder: 'lieu' %>
   <%= f.input :country, as: :select, collection: country_options_for_select, include_blank: 'Pays', label: 'Pays' %>
  <%= f.input :photos, as: :text, placeholder: 'photos' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Valider', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

I use gem "select_country" to display list of countries in a select.
I want to store the full name country in my user table.
But now, it store just "FR". How to do this ?
In application_helper.rb :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def country_options_for_select
    countries = ISO3166::Country.all.map { |c| [c.translations['en'], c.alpha2] }
    countries
  end
end
```

I use gem "select_country" to display list of countries in a select.
I want to store the full name country in my user table.
But now, it store just "FR". How to do this ?
How to make it store "France" instead of "FR" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask you to double check if you really want to save the name, rather than the alpha2. You can always render it to the full name in the users locale in whatever view you want to display this. It's more versatile this way.

However, if you do want save the name of the country in English, rather than alpha2, you can change your `ApplicationHelper` to:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def country_options_for_select
    countries = ISO3166::Country.all.map { |c| [c.translations['en'], c.common_name] }
    countries
  end
end
```

Or use `[c.translations['en']` for both.

See [line 109](https://github.com/countries/countries/blob/master/lib/countries/country.rb) on the gems code:

`# @return [String] the “common name” of this Country in English.`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done in another way. Finally, I use Geocoder to autocomplete.